# Any way to determine if the camera is idle?

Tags: android-camera

I'm working with the raw camera image, but need to restart the preview following the capture of an image. When i call startPreview() following takePicture, the android hangs because the camera is till in use. I've waited till after the raw image has been written to disk, but the camera is still in use, so the start preview still hangs the system.

```
camera.takePicture(null, null, null);
(test needed here){
camera.startPreview();      
}
```

Putting the start preview in the rawcallback hangs the android.

When calling takePicture, the jpegCallback occurs after the camera is finished, so it is safe to start the preview, but this also creates a .jpg.

The question is following the takePicture, is there any way to determine when the camera is idle? (other than the jpegCallback?).

I've found ways around the problem, such as starting the preview on a timer, but still wonder if there is any way to determine the actual status of the camera and a way to test when it is save to restart the preview.

Comment: knowing your specific goal here would be helpful in terms of actually helping you accomplish your goal as opposed to just answering your stated question (determining if the 'status' of the camera can be known––it is busy until JPEG callback).

Comment: The application is a dot based barcode application, where the size of the dots are VERY small. For my purpose, the most effective image format to work with is the raw file direct from the camera chip. The other consideration was taking a full resolution .jpg and calling BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray to get a bitmap resulted in memory problems. The api would seem to indicate that the jpegcallback is optional, so it would seem there is some way to not need it. Then again, the api said the rawimagecallback would give a raw image, so much for the documentation.

Comment: Oh I see.. so you want the raw callback for full resolution due to the small size of the dots? Are you trying to immediately restart the preview because you want some sort of seamless image capture that doesn't disrupt the user experience or pause the camera preview?

Comment: Its more complicated than that. I'm using a service to receive a request from a pc to take a photo. The service sends a message to a message handler in the main app, which takes a picture. I was hoping to handle the entire request in the message handler, where the picture callback goes off and does its own thing. It would be nice is I could have just checked the camera to be free within the message handler, rather than involve the callback.

Comment: so you want to ensure that when the service receives the request, the camera is free to take a photo?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76224276/9585130

Answer (score 0):

After calling the [takePicture() function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29), you must wait until the JPEG callback has returned for the camera to be ready to use again. There is no way to monitor its status. The documentation explicitly states the following:

> After calling this method, you must not call startPreview() or take
>   another picture until the JPEG callback has returned.

If you need some fast way of grabbing frames (i.e. images) without stopping and restarting the camera preview, you can implement the [PreviewCallback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html) interface which will simply allow you to grab preview frames without stopping the preview at all. Just remember that you will need to convert these from YUV format (which is not difficult using Android's [YUVImage class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html).

Comment: I'm not calling jpegcallback, so it is difficult to wait till it finishes. I'm starting to guess that the .jpg is created if or if not the jpegcallback is called, so calling jpegcallback just to restart the preview may not be adding any overhead. The raw bayer image is as the camera sees it, everything else is post processing.

Comment: yeah. don't think the jpegcallback adds any overhead.