# Android: How to get a callback in CameraX when the camera device has finished opening?

Tags: android, android-camerax

I want to apply the white balance and exposure values when the cameraX has finished opening. Is there a way to get camera opened callback the same as `CameraDevice.StateCallback` in Camera2?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a callback for the camera availability, but there is one for the preview.

**Callback for preview visibility:**

Use: `previewView.previewStreamState.observe(previewObserver)`

The `previewObserver` object initialization:

```kotlin
previewObserver = Observer { streamState ->
    if (streamState == PreviewView.StreamState.STREAMING) { // if preview visible
        // todo
    } else if (streamState == PreviewView.StreamState.IDLE) { // if preview not visible
        // todo
    }
}
```

*preview not visible means that you don't see the camera preview(not streaming), and vice-versa

Comment: Thank you @Raz Leshem for your answer. If I apply white balance and brightness after opening camera preview, the preview blinks. To prevent this blinking, i need to set brightness after the camera is ready.

Comment: I have played with the exposure compensation(brightness) plenty and never had this issue, so I don't think that is what causes the preview to "blink", so if you could share in what practice you applied the white balance maybe I can help somehow...

Answer (score 0):

##### Update 2023

I am using Jetpack Compose

```
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

previewView.previewStreamState.observe(lifecycleOwner) { streamState ->
    if (streamState == PreviewView.StreamState.STREAMING) {
        print("camera STREAMING")
    } else if (streamState == PreviewView.StreamState.IDLE) {
        print("camera IDLE")
    }
}
```

Hope this help!